# Cmake can not find QT4 during install

Tags: cmake, gnuradio, qt4

I used

```
sudo-apt get install qwtplot3d-qt4-0
```

to install qwtplot3d. However when running cmake I get the following:

```
 CMake Error at /usr/local/share/cmake-3.4/Module/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:148
 (message):   Could NOT find Qt4 (missing: QT_QWTPLOT3D_INCLUDE_DIR
 QT_QWTPLOT3D_LIBRARY)   (found suitable version "4.8.6", minimum
 required is "4.2.0") Call Stack (most recent call first):  
 /usr/local/share/cmake-3.4/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:388
(_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)  
 /usr/local/share/cmake-3.4/Modules/FindQt4.cmake:1333
 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)   CMakeLists.txt:152
 (find_package)
```

I'm not sure if the issue is QT4 or QWTPLOT3D

> 

Comment: From the package page: http://packages.ubuntu.com/source/xenial/qwtplot3d   it looks like the package you are trying to install has several dependencies first. Hence you can try to install the dependencies and then go for  installing  ` qwtplot3d-qt4-0`

Comment: @ankit7540 When trying to install the dependencies from that page some of them don't seem to install. So when I use sudo apt-get build-dep libqwtplot3d-qt5-dev  to check the dependencies of a dependency ....E: Unable to find a source package for libqwtplot3d-qt5-dev

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using? what package did you install exactly? (the development package on my 16.04 system seems to be called `libqwtplot3d-qt4-dev`)

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 14.04(trusty) and I installed 'libqwtplot3d-qt4-doc' 'libqwtplot3d-qwt-0' and 'libqwtplot3d-qt4-dev'. After those 3 installs cmake is able to run without issues. However, when I run make I get errors.'In file included from /home/rell320/gr-inspector/lib/vis3d_vf_form.h:34:0,
                 from /home/rell320/gr-inspector/lib/vis3d_vf_form.cc:23:
        /home/rell320/gr-inspector/lib/signal_marker.h:28:31: fatal error: qwt_plot_zoneitem.h: No such file or directory
       #include <qwt_plot_zoneitem.h>
                               ^
       compilation terminated'